# Nginx adding path to location

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I'm new to Nginx and is having trouble displaying my index.html

My very basic config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8080;

    root /opt/app/static;
    index index.html

    location /mypath {
        alias /opt/app/static/;
        autoindex off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
    alias /opt/app/static/favicon.ico;
    }
}
```

And the url I'm trying to access, which should display my index.html, looks like this `https://my_subdomain.test.domain.com/mypath`

However, I get 404 error.

```
[error] 9#0: *12 "/opt/app/static/mypath/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xx.x.x, server: , request: "GET /mypath/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my_subdomain.test.domain.com"
```

Nginx is adding the url path to the search path for my index.html

I've also tried to set `location /mypath {` to `location / {` without success.

How can I setup my config so that when I access `https://my_subdomain.test.domain.com/mypath` nginx is displaying index.html that is located in path `/opt/app/static/`?

Comment: Try `location ^~ /mypath`

Answer (score 0):

Your server is looking for /mypath/ but you only told it to look for /mypath

Try

```
location ^/mypath {
    alias /opt/app/static/;
    autoindex off;
}
```

or

```
location ~ /mypath {
    alias /opt/app/static/;
    autoindex off;
}
```